# Retrieve nested values from mixed PHP array

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.4 and getting back array structures like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [HGS-SUB] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 59.00
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DOMN-MTH] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 25.00
                )

        )

)
```

I can't figure out how to retrieve (for example) the string "HGS-SUB" and the number "59.00" within a `foreach` loop. Note: `HGS-SUB` is dynamic data that is not known until runtime, so I can't hardcode it. Here is my `foreach`:

```
foreach ($matchingProducts as $key => $value){
    EmitObjectDetails($value);
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [HGS-SUB] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 59.00
        )

)


Array
(
    [DOMN-MTH] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 25.00
        )

)
```

My desire result for the 1st iteration of the loop is to capture the string "HGS-SUB" and the number "59.00". Similarly, in the 2nd iteration of the loop I want to capture the string "DOMN-MTH" and "25.00".

I have tried all sorts of experiments such as:

- $value[0]
- $value[$key];
- $value->{0}
- $value[0][0]

Nothing works. Please help.

Comment: You need to nest another foreach loop

Comment: Can you add to the question how you generate this array as it seems to be part of a SimpleXMLElement object;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick without an extra foreach:

```
foreach ($matchingProducts as $key => $value) {

    $string  =  key($value);
    $number  =  $value[$string]->{0};

    echo $string .' '. $number ."\n";
}
```

Using `key()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) will return your "unknown key name" of the `$value` array. Then you can use that "now-known key" with the `$value` array to pull the inner property of the object (that property being of `0` according to your example).

---

This is a working test example:

```
// Making up a dummy to match your example content:
$matchingProducts = array();
$row1 = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root></root>', null, false);
$row2 = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root></root>', null, false);
$row1->{0} = '59.00';
$row2->{0} = '25.00';
$matchingProducts[0] = array('HGS-SUB'=> $row1 );
$matchingProducts[1] = array('DOMN-MTH'=> $row2 );

print_r($matchingProducts);

foreach($matchingProducts as $key => $value) {

    $string = key($value);
    $number = $value[$string]->{0};

    echo $string .' '. $number ."\n";
}
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [HGS-SUB] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>                 (
>                     [0] => 59.00
>                 )
>
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [DOMN-MTH] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>                 (
>                     [0] => 25.00
>                 )
>
>         )
>
> )
> HGS-SUB 59.00
> DOMN-MTH 25.00
> ```

Comment: Works great, thanks IncredibleHat! But how can you have `key` without a `$` in front of it?

Comment: Function `key()`  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)... it grabs the key of the current array pointer. (updated answer with this bit too)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `foreach` and then check if element is `is_array`.

Or you need to define a function which should return all elements of array and that function should be called recursive if element is array.